Обособление слова «считайте»
«Если о вас скажут такое, считайте, что удостоились похвалы».
Почему «считайте» с обеих сторон выделено запятой?

Запятая слева, потому что очевидно это две разные основы - скажут и считайте.
Все портит подчинительный союз "что", потому что если бы его не было, то вторая запятая была бы не нужна:
«Если о вас скажут такое, считайте удостоились похвалы.»
Вот так запятая вовсе не обязательно, потому что:

Примечания: 1. Не являются обращениями и не выделяются запятыми
названия лиц/предметов, находящиеся при форме повелительного
наклонения глагола, если она употреблена в значении пожелания
(пусть…): Приходи к нему лечиться и корова и волчица (Чук.); Всяк
сверчок знай свой шесток (Посл.); ср. также: Кто постарше садитесь. Розенталь.

Хотя нет, вру. Считайте и глагол другой основы всегда разделяются запятой, в редких случаях ставят тире.
«Если о вас скажут такое, считайте, удостоились похвалы.»
«Если о вас скажут такое, считайте - удостоились похвалы.»(редко)
А вот если это не глагол, тогда допустимо без запятой:
«Если о вас скажут такое, считайте удостоенной похвалы.»
«Если о вас скажут такое, считайте удостоившихся похвалы»
«Если о вас скажут такое, считайте похвалой.»
И редкий случай, когда "считайте как хотите" - без запятой:
«Если о вас скажут такое, считайте как хотите.»
НО! Это потому что глагол "считайте" часто вроде вводного слова, скорее всего. А вот с другими глаголами это далеко не всегда так.

— Эй вы, на пузыре! Подплывайте ближе, дайте разглядеть вас! Куда
там — подплывайте! 1960
И разрешите пофантазировать: быть может; недалеко то время, когда
астрофизические явления на Солнце мы будем предсказывать, изучая под
микроскопом изменчивость микроорганизмов. 1960
Того ради извольте приказать справиться, и ежели не положены, то,
взяв от той канторы подлинную выправку, прислать ко мне. Татищев.
— Перестаньте убивать нас, невинных. Фонвизин.

Почему так происходит? Вероятно, глаголы области представлений разделяются с глаголами действий:

Вчера студент Никольский поспорил с приятелями на бутылку шампанского,
что незаметно вынесет эту голову, и, представьте себе, вынес.
Представьте: просыпаетесь вы ночью и... видите прямо над собой жарко
дышащую раззявленную клыкастую пасть.

Когда необходимо показать различие между замыслом и действием, такие глаголы разделяются запятыми или другими разделительными средствами. Если же глаголы касаются одного сложного действия, то могут и не разделяться.
Возможно, поэтому "считайте как хотите" - не обособляются, так как оба глагола относятся к области замысла-представления, а не один к области представлений, а другой к действию.
И вот тут могут возникать разные странные случаи:
Ты зовешь меня въ Пензу, а того и гляди что я поѣду далѣе. Пушкин.
— Как чего боюсь, батюшка Кирила Петрович, а Дубровского-то; того и гляди попадешься ему в лапы. Пушкин.
Хотя, казалось бы, "того и гляди" должно быть вводным - ан нет. Пушкин даже при ЧТО запятую ставить не стал, а сделал все сложным союзом "а того и гляди что". И ряд других писателей тоже не обособляли, а вот Гоголь - обособлял.

С закатом солнца мы причаливаем к берегу, потому что в потемках того и
гляди наткнешься на какую-нибудь песчаную отмель. Гончаров.
— Да и в самом деле, как приберетесь его? землишка маленькая, мужик
ленив, работать не любит, думает, как бы в кабак... того и гляди,
пойдешь на старости лет по миру! Гоголь.


• Это сложноподчиненное предложение с двумя придаточными частями.
Главное предложение считайте отделяется от придаточных запятыми, поэтому и выделено с двух сторон (подлежащего в нем нет, но оно подразумевается):
Если о вас скажут такое, [вы] считайте, что удостоились похвалы.
• Вот пример с точно такой же структурой предложения и пунктуацией:
— Если я не вынырну, считайте, что вы меня нокаутировали, — сказал он, улыбкой перехватывая ее улыбку и доводя ее до нахальных размеров (Фазиль Искандер. Время счастливых находок).
• Можно перестроить предложение, и тогда будет понятно, что оба придаточных с союзами что и если относятся к одному главному (считайте).
[Вы] Считайте, что удостоились похвалы, если о вас скажут такое.
• Слово считайте (или считай) действительно может быть вводным словом.
Но не в нашем предложении.
Знаки препинания в сложноподчиненном предложении (ПАС)

Считай(те) – вводное слово, выделяется с двух сторон знаками препинания:
Если проснулся ночью, считай, пропал.

Правильно:
Если о вас скажут такое, считайте, что удостоились похвалы.
Сложноподчиненное предложение (СПП) с двумя придаточными (союзы ЕСЛИ и ЧТО). Придаточные условное и изъяснительное.
Считайте — главное предложение, односоставное, выражено глаголом в повелительном наклонении.
